# How to add text in dynamically added EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I want to add text to my dynamically added EditTexts.
As for now its just adding a layout with two EditText in, its getting added to a LinearLayout on button click.

How do I set the text of these Editexts? Because now I can add as many as I like and every EditText has the same id as the have in the layout file.

My mainactivity.java with the inflation upon button clicklooks like this:

```
final LinearLayout mView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.more_rest_main, null);
mView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
restLayout.addView(mView);
```

And here is my layout for more_rest_main.xml

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/added_rest_from"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/time_from"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:focusable="false"/>

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/added_rest_to"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="@string/time_to"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand here is that you can look for a child view in any `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout` is a `ViewGroup`).

You're probably familiar with retrieving a `View` in an Activity `onCreate`, where after calling `setContentView`, you have access to any `View` with `findViewById`.

So after inflating your `ViewGroup`, you can use the same approach you would use in an Activity `onCreate`, but you need to look for your ViewGroup's child views:

```
final LinearLayout mView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.more_rest_main, null);

EditText txtAddedRestFrom = (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.added_rest_from);

restLayout.addView(mView);
```

Once you have your reference you can invoke any method on your EditText, such as [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType)).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EditText dynamically like following:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(myContext);
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//add the same logic as in the XML file
mView.addView(editText);
```

You can also set an ID dynamically. If you are using API 17 and above, do the following:

```
editText.setId(View.generateViewId())
```

Otherwise you can set a positive Integer of your choice as an ID, instead of using the:

```
View.generateViewId()
```

With the code above and since these will be added dynamically, you don't need the XML file as the EditTexts will be created dynamically. 
If you want to keep the existing XML file, you can just call the

```
setTag()
```

to each one of the inflated EditTexts and set a unique value in the setTag method. That way you can distinguish the EditTexts. And since you can do that, you can add whatever text you need to each one of them.

To reply to your comment, on how to set an OnCLickListener:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // here you can get either the Tag or the ID that
       // you've set dynamically. And do whatever you like to do
       view.getTag()
       view.getId()
    }
});
```

Comment: How does this method work if I want to add a clicklistener

Comment: @alexandermogren Where do you want to add the clicklistener?

Comment: I want to add a clicklistener after that the edittexts has dynamcally been created and check if you click it.

Comment: @alexandermogren Please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: I think that I am not doing things right here. My function for my button [looks like this](http://pastebin.com/USPKYzT0). And also I have a little illustration [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6iKKwgV3RQ)

Comment: If I am adding a view with **restLayout.addView(mView);** why is it not that simple to remove it with **restLayout.removeView(mView);** ?